# windows cmd - execute commands in shortcut

Tags: cmd, shortcut

I want to understand how I can run 2 .bat commands in a shortcut.

This are the 2 commands:

```
cd my_programm\startscripts\windows
start designer.cmd
```

How do I have to convert these commands to run from a shortcut?

I know I can run cmd with it:

```
%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /c "" ...

/c to execute the commands and then close the command line
"" to start in the current directory, because I use a relative path
```

But how do I have to write the two commands to use them as start parameters?

Comment: Why do you use `start`? any particular reason? Anyway, try `cmd /C start "" /D "D:\my_programm\startscripts\windows" "designer.cmd"`; or `cmd /C call "D:\my_programm\startscripts\windows\designer.cmd"`?

Comment: You don't! What you do is make the string in the `Start in:` field read as `"D:\my_programm\startscripts\windows"`, and then in your `Target:` field the string would be `"D:\my_programm\startscripts\windows\designer.cmd"`. _I would advise in both cases that you keep the double-quotes too, although with the string you've provided, those are probably not essential_.

Comment: That's not what I wanted. I want to have a relative path in my command. This has to work somehow with %CD%.